# Where the parameters of main coming from in Dart?

Tags: dart

I can use any of the following:

```dart
void main() {}
```

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {}
```

But I want to know how and where the `main` function is defined in Dart that it can either have no arguments or arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the [language specification](https://spec.dart.dev/DartLangSpecDraft.pdf). Section "19.6 Scripts" describes the process in which scripts are entered.

`main` can actually take a second argument as well, though it's not an error to exclude that argument as the following quoted specification describes:

> A script is a library whose exported namespace (19.2) includes a
> top-level function declaration named main that has either zero, one
> or two required arguments. ...
>
> If main can be called with with two
> positional arguments, it is invoked with the following two actual
> arguments:
>
> 1. An object whose run-time type implements List<String>.
> 2. An object specified when the current isolate i was created, for example through the invocation of Isolate.spawnUri that spawned i, or
>    the null object (17.4) if no such object was supplied.
>
> If main cannot
> be called with two positional arguments, but it can be called with one
> positional argument, it is invoked with an object whose run-time type
> implements List<String> as the only argument. If main cannot be called
> with one or two positional arguments, it is invoked with no arguments.

Comment: What is the type of second parameter in `main`?

Comment: @iDecode As the quoted documentation says "An object specified when the current isolate i was created, for example through the invocation of Isolate.spawnUri that spawned i". So you could say it's dynamic.

Comment: If I were this good in English, I wouldn't have asked you haha.

Comment: @iDecode You could look at the [`Isolate.spawnUri`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate/spawnUri.html) method that was mentioned. You can pass any data you want. It's up to whatever spawns the isolate.